# Hitting ashx from remote client receives 403 error when Method used is Delete

Tags: asp.net, ajax, security

I use jquery uploader, which works fine when running the app from the server. But when I try to Delete an uploaded file to a remote server, which submits the form with "DELETE" as Method to an ashx file that I have implemented. Firebug reveals that the request did hit the server, but 403 Forbidden was served. I have a break point in the Delete segment of the code, and it is never hit (as expected.)

Given that, I suspect that there must be some .NET configuration that I have to do to make it work. When running the app from a browser on the same server works fine, so I am guessing it maybe permission. Any help, please?

Comment: What does your web.config look like where you have the handler registered?

Comment: <location path="uploadReceiver.ashx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow the verb, example below:

```
<httpHandlers> 
    <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.ashx" 
         verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory"
         resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</httpHandlers>
```

ref: [Enabling The PUT Verb with Handlers and IIS 7.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joseph_fultz/archive/2009/07/23/enabling-the-put-verb-with-handlers-and-iis-7-0.aspx)

Comment: Isn't DELETE a legitimate verb as well?

Comment: yes, DELETE is a legitimate verb. That's why he put it into his sample code.

Comment: are you using "System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" as an example? I added this to <httpHandlers> section and it still doesn't let me delete. Uploading and Listing current files works fine.

Comment: It's an example, add it to your handler, you haven't provided any info about yours.

Comment: The funny thing is, it works for GET's and POST's, just not DELETE. If it weren't registered at all, then why are the other 2 Methods working?

Comment: I got it to work by adding delete keyword to the verb in Application Configuration (http://i.imgur.com/0ivCn.png). I still don't know how to translate that into a web.config entry. Is it exactly as your answer says?